# INNER JOIN + JOIN returning duplicating result

Tags: sql-server, join

I have a SQL Server query that it trying to connect 3 tables. I am getting the results I need, but have a duplication issue.

`table1` is the main record table. `table2` is basically a user table. `table3` is a lookup table that connects users to managers.

I need to connect one user to all the records connected to himself and any other users connected to his manager (or the people he manages, if a manager). All managers are users, and any user can 'own' a record on `table1`.

`table3` connects userIDs on `table2` to the userID of the manager also on `table2`.

```
table3 (lookup table)
id | altID
15 | 205
16 | 205
17 | 205
18 | 246

table2 (user table)
id | other_col
15 | abc
16 | def
17 | ggg
18 | hhh
205| yyy
246| zzz

table1 (record table)
id | record_data
15 | abc
16 | def
17 | ggg
18 | hhh
205| yyy
246| zzz
```

The user will put in their ID. So if id = 'XYZ'.

```
SELECT c.id, c.col, s.col2, s.col3
 FROM table1 AS c
 INNER JOIN table2 AS s
  ON c.id = s.id
 JOIN table3 AS p
  ON c.id = p.id OR c.id = p.altID
 WHERE
  (p.id = 'XYZ'
  OR p.altID = 'XYZ')
 AND
  (c.id = p.altID
  OR c.id = p.id)
 AND
  NULLIF(LTRIM(RTRIM(c.column)), '') IS NOT null
```

This is giving me all the associated records (all the users that XYZ is related to). It is, however, including XYZ twice, and I cannot figure out why.

This is resolvable using `DISTINCT(c.id)` in the `SELECT` statement, but I am trying to understand why the duplication happens to begin with.

Comment: First: INNER JOIN and JOIN are synonyms. Second: what you mean by "So if id = 'XYZ'." - table3 does not have values 'XYZ'. Third: if you mean by 'XYZ'  values in (15,16,17,18,205, 246) - it's absolutely normal that you have doubles for 205.

Answer (score 1):

Here’s what I get when I work through the logic in the query:

- The join from table1 (c) to table2 (s) is one-to one, as (s) contains a single row with the “name” for the Id in (c). No duplciation problems there.
- You then join table1 (c) to table 3 (p), from the “owing” id in (c) to all rows in (p) for that id, for both user and manager columns. Thus, if the item in (c) is owned by a manager, you will get one or more hits, once for them as a user *and* once for *each* time they are a manager.

Leastways, that’s what I figure based solely on the code and the descriptions you provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to show the relation USER - MANAGER defined in `table3` one posible way is to join the lookup table (table3) again with the user table (to get the manager record).

```
SELECT c.id, s.other_col, p.altid, manager.other_col manager_name 
 FROM table1 c
 JOIN table2 s
  ON c.id = s.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table3 p
  ON c.id = p.id
 LEFT OUTER JOIN table2 manager
  ON p.altid = manager.id;

        ID OTHER_COL      ALTID MANAGER_NAME
---------- --------- ---------- ------------
        17 ggg              205 yyy          
        16 def              205 yyy          
        15 abc              205 yyy          
        18 hhh              246 zzz          
       246 zzz                               
       205 yyy
```

I'm using OUTER JOIN, that will show also users withou manager. INNER JOIN will suppress those records.